# Partial page inside colorbox fails to trigger onclick handler of radio buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my index page I have

```
<a class='popup' href='@Url.Action("Add", "Alert")'>Add New</a>
```

I have a section script at the end of the cshtml file

```
@section Scripts 
{ 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.formmail-maker.com/var/demo/jquery-popup-    form/colorbox.css" />

<style>
    #cboxOverlay{ background:#666666; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".popup").colorbox({ opacity: 0.85, iframe: true, fastIframe: false, width:    "450px", height: "480px", scrolling: false });
});

function ddUserClicked() { 
{
    alert('user button, selected!'); 
}

function ddEntityClicked() {
    alert('entity button, selected!');
}

</script>

}
```

This works fine. When the Add (action method) Alert (controller) is invoked, it returns a partial page that happily fills the colorbox at the center of the page.

In the colorbox I have two radio buttons. I was hoping to use the onclick event so that they can invoke the functions I implemented from the originating view, ddUserClicked() and ddEntityClicked().

But this does not work.

The partial page script is

```
@model WellRoute.Web.Models.CreateAlertModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add New Alert";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2><br />

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Alert", FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>New Alert</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Type")</td>
            <td>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsUserAlert, true, new { onclick = "ddUserClicked(); ", })User Alert
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsUserAlert, false, new { onclick = "ddEntityClicked()", })Entity Alert
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("User")</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.Users, "Id", "EmailAddress"), new { style = "width:250px;" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.Entities, "Id", "Name"), new { style = "width:250px; visibility:hidden;"     })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Message")</td>
            <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new  { style = "width:250px; height:100px" })</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I see (not sure if that is just a copy'n'paste-error though) is that you have one `{` too much on your `ddUserClicked()`-function :)

Other than that, a quick and dirty way to get it to work would be to remove the functions `ddUserClicked` and `ddEntityClicked` from your view and put the following at the top of the partial view instead (not inside a `script`-section though)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ddUserClicked() {
        alert('user button, selected!');
    }

    function ddEntityClicked() {
        alert('entity button, selected!');
    }
</script>
```

I think the problem might be that the `script`-section is included at the end of the `body` (if you're using the default `_Layout.cshtml` at least) and that the functions aren't defined at the point where you're using them. I could be wrong though.

Another way to do it would be to give the radio buttons an ID instead, like:

```
<td>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsUserAlert, true, new { id = "user_alert", })User Alert
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsUserAlert, false, new { id = "entity_alert", })Entity Alert
</td>
```

... And then create a jquery-script. Something along the lines of:

```
// File alert.js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user_alert").click(function() {
        alert('user button, selected!');
    });

    $("#entity_alert").click(function () {
        alert('user button, selected!');
    });
});
```

And then link the .js. This will give you a loose coupling towards the script since you don't specify any functions to bind to in the HTML. Generally, you want to avoid putting too much javascript in your views.

Comment: I just realized that I'm not sure if click() will work with radiobuttons. Haven't tried it myself. Might be change() you're looking for.